# React on state change in content (Windows Phone)

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1

Is it possible for the content of a control to react to visual state change of its parent?

In the following example I'd like the textblock's foreground to change to red, when parent control is active. But this code doesn't work:

```
<local:ExpandKeyButton x:Name="xpand" Height="30">
    <TextBlock x:Name="tb">
        Test
        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="General">
                <VisualState x:Name="Idle" />
                <VisualState x:Name="Active">
                    <Storyboard>
                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="tb" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Red" />
                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    </Storyboard>
                </VisualState>
            </VisualStateGroup>
        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
    </TextBlock>
</local:ExpandKeyButton>
```

Comment: The storyboard can target inward -- that is, if you set the VisualStateGroups on local:ExpandKeyButton, it can still modify the TextBlock

Comment: @bdimag the first part is true, but the second is not, because `VisualStateGroups` would be invalid there.  VisualStateGroups can only be defined under the root element of a ControlTemplate or UserControl.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No -- the visual states are internal to the control, in the sense that UI elements outside the owning ControlTemplate cannot (directly) participate in visual state changes.  I could see a few possibilities in your scenario:

1. If the "tb" TextBlock is a general feature of the "ExpandKeyButton", then move it inside the ControlTemplate, to allow it to participate in visual state changes.
2. Or, for a more loosely-coupled approach, add either a property or an event to the "ExpandKeyButton" control, to allow the TextBlock to bind to its state.  For example, you could add an "IsActive" dependency property, which you could set appropriately inside the ControlTemplate's VisualStateManager -- and then the TextBlock could use a binding like `Foreground="{Binding ElementName=xpand,Path=IsActive,Converter={StaticResource ActiveToColorConverter}}"` to make it red when the control is active.